# grep with unassigned variable exits a loop unexpectedly

Tags: bash, while-loop, stdin

I have a simple bash script that, so far, just reads the each line of a file and prints it. Simple enough:

```
while read i
do
  echo $i
  #otherViewDef=`grep -i $currentView $viewssqlfile`
done <$viewsdeffile
```

This script works as expected, unless the commented line is uncommented. If this is this case, the loop exits after echoing the first line of the file. I understand that this should not work as both `currentView` and `viewsqlfile` are unset, but what is the justification for this behavior as opposed to reporting an error and giving a non-zero return signal?

Comment: Always [quote your variables](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/13377) in bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's something different; this can't be the actual script, because the errors would be different. Assuming `$currentView` is set but `$viewssqlfile` is not, the assignment executes

```
grep -i $currentView
```

which reads from stdin, which means it greps the contents of `$viewsdeffile`. It finds no matches, so prints nothing. After that, the `read i` has nothing to read, returns false, and the loop exits.

In other words, if the controlling `read` of a loop reads from a redirected stdin, make sure *no program in the loop body* attempts to reads from stdin as well; they all share the same stdin. 
Placing `set -x` near the top is likely to provide some insight.

Comment: You're correct, except it's backwards. `$viewssqlfile` is set, `$currentView` is not, but your point still stands.  grep still takes one non-option argument and messes with what's in stdin.

I read in another post on SO that the `while read i` is the proper way to iterate through a file line-by-line, but if your loop contains reading from stdin, this doesn't seem to be the case. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You *can* have programs in the loop read stdin, but they usually should redirect it from a *different* file, e.g. you could write `grep foo < bar` which wouldn't gobble up data from `$viewsdeffile`.